# Send values between functions

Tags: r, function

I have a standalone function that takes several options:

```
distance2thing <- function(in_file="data/classes_input.txt",sim=NA, send=0, feature='start'){

  cat("Feature selected = ", feature, "\n")

  # ...

}
```

Here, the most important thing is that users can specify their own `feature`. If they don't specify anything, the default value of `'start'` will be used.

I have a second function that calls this first function with options:

```
callDistance2thing <- function(feature='start'){
  real_data<-distance2thing(send=1, feature)
}
```

However, whatever value I specify for `feature` in `callDistance2thing()` gets overwritten by `distance2thing(feature='start')`.

I've also tried setting the `feature` to `NA` in `distance2thing()`, but this has the same effect.

How can I have a function that has a default value, and another function that calls that first function with a user-specified value?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `feature = feature` inside the `callDistance2thing` function's call of `distance2thing`?

Comment: @LAP - You mean `real_data<-distance2thing(send=1, feature = feature)`

Comment: `feature` is being passed to `in_file` by position; add `print(in_file)` to `distance2thing` to see

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you are overwriting the feature value again with feature='start'?

[Example in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJEb.png)

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem